# Update a field in other records based on the value of same field in a record automatically

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I want to transfer the contents (value) of a field in an Access form by VBA to its previous and next records, while I am still in the current record. Could be said I want to copy it to the same field but into other records same time.

For example, a worker has several different records in a form specific to himself in a database. If his working hours changed in a record, the working hours stored in a field must be transferred to other records automatically (or manually by a button and macro or VBA connected to it).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to enforce referential integrity with the tables you want the data to transfer to. You can setup relationships between your tables, enforce referential integrity, and then choose to cascade update or delete the relevant tables when values are modified. This sounds like what you are trying to accomplish, but it also sounds like your data is not normalized so this approach may be completely out the window.

If you are trying to simply copy the values of one record to the immediate next or previous record in the table, this can definitely be done pretty simply in VBA. You can use one of the form update methods (OnUpdate, BeforeUpdate, AfterUpdate) to catch those changes when the form's field is modified (so no button). Then, it's just a matter of taking the data, grabbing the id of the current record, iterating forward or back one, and replacing the data in those records.

Here is the documentation of the afterUpdate method for reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.afterupdate-event

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have to say that there are no multiple tables! We only have one table that contains the entire profile of a worker, but this information appears in several different forms. And of course, each worker has his own unique table. For example, the same form that we are talking about contains information about the worker's working hours, the worker's place of work, the type of work, his salary and his supervisor. Other forms display other information. One shows the history of the projects he has done, and the other shows his family details, etc.

Comment: I don't want to transfer the values of one record to the next or previous record, but I want to transfer only the information of two or three fields of one record to several other records (without changing the information of other fields) and at the same time.
Thanks Again!

Comment: As a sample:
A worker has a work table with 29 records. I want all records be automatically updated when an employee's hours on a record change. For example, when record number 17 in a form changes in the "working time" field, then the same field in other records (from record No. 1 to No. 16 and then from No. 18 to No. 29) will updated automatically.